# Python newspaper library issues and errors

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-newspaper

I am using the Python newspaper library which is running on a Linux vps server:

- the first issue relates to the newspaper sites whose articles I'm trying to parse saying I'm using adblocker so they don't show any articles as they want me to deactivate it. I obviously don't have it running. It seems something needs to be added to the header of the request but I'm not sure what or how. Some help would be appreciated.
- the second relates to some errors I'm getting when I run the script.

The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/PIL/ImageFile.py", line 100, in __init__
    self._open()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/PIL/PngImagePlugin.py", line 514, in _open
    self.png.crc(cid, s)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/PIL/PngImagePlugin.py", line 142, in crc
    crc2 = i16(self.fp.read(2)), i16(self.fp.read(2))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/PIL/_binary.py", line 53, in i16be
    return unpack(">H", c[o:o+2])[0]
struct.error: unpack requires a bytes object of length 2
```

If I'm missing anything please do let me know and I can update. My code is as follows:

```
import newspaper
import pymysql
import time

def InitialiseDB():
    db = pymysql.connect(host="localhost",# your host, usually localhost
                         user="xxx",         # your username
                         passwd="yyyyyyyy",  # your password
                         db="testdb",        # name of the data base
                         autocommit=True, use_unicode=True, charset="utf8")
    cur = db.cursor()
    return cur    

def CloseDB(cur):
    cur.close()

def GetListOfMediaURLs(cur):
    cur.execute("SELECT sourceid, sourcename, sourceurl FROM MediaSources limit 5")
    rows = cur.fetchall();
    return rows

def SaveArticleInDB(sourceid, cur, article):
        article.download()
        article.parse()    
        if ("ad-block" in article.text):
                return
        article.nlp()
        print(article.keywords)
        print(article.summary)    
        date = time.strftime("%c")
        html = pymysql.escape_string(article.html)
        authors = ', '.join('?' * len(article.authors))
        movies = ', '.join('?' * len(article.movies))
        keywords = ', '.join('?' * len(article.keywords))    
        cur.execute(
           """INSERT INTO FullArticlesImported (url, title, publishdate, text, html, authors, sourceid, topimage, movies, keywords, summary, importdate)
              VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)""",
              (article.url, article.title, article.publish_date, article.text, html, authors, sourceid, article.top_image, movies, keywords, article.summary, date))    
        cur = InitialiseDB()    
        mediasources = GetListOfMediaURLs(cur)    
        for mediasource in mediasources:
        # Grab each article and store it in the db
        print ("Processing... "+mediasource[1])
        paper = newspaper.build(mediasource[2], memoize_articles=False)   
        # Extract the brand name, description for each url
        print(paper.brand+" "+paper.description)
        if paper.size()==0:
            print("No of articles are 0!!!")    
        for article in paper.articles:
            dir(article)
            SaveArticleInDB(mediasource[0], cur, article)   
        CloseDB(cur)
        quit()
```

Comment: Your problem seems to be related to [PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/) (`/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/PIL/_binary.py`)

Comment: which version of newspaper are you trying to use? 3 or 2.7?